# How do I intercept and modify HTTP Auth requests from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Based on the documentation I have written the following code as a background script:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    function (details, callback) {
        console.log('onAuthRequired', details);
        callback({
            authCredentials: {username: "alpha", password: "beta"}
        });
    },
    {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
    ['asyncBlocking']
);
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details, callback) {
        console.log('onBeforeRequest', details);
    },
    {urls: ['<all_urls>']}
);
```

The `onBeforeRequest` callback works, but the `onAuthRequired` callback does not. I do not seem to get `'onBeforeRequest'` printed to the console as I expect. What is missing?

My intention is simply to automatically provide auth credentials for a specific domain. A working example of this would suffice as an answer.

Comment: Do you have the `webRequestBlocking` permission in your manifest?

Comment: That did the trick! If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it. Thanks. (p.s. gosh this documentation is useless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but you'll need to use the `webRequestBlocking` permission in addition to the plain `webRequest` permission.